# Hellip symbol isn't working inside the URL address

Tags: html

The address below is not working in my ePub. It says that `...` (hellip) is not valid:

```
http://www.connectingforhealth.nhs.uk/…/infogov/…/infogovleaflet.pdf
```

Is there any way to include this in URL?

Answer (score 1):

As a non-ASCII character, "…" must be URL encoded to `%E2%80%A6`.

Comment: I got it, the separator is #125 and it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your answer deceze.